# Ember Data: Filtering on hasMany by id without fetching object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model with a hasMany collection, and I would like to determine whether or not an object exists in that collection, given the ID of an object.

```
var searchFor = "someid";
var filtered = parent.get('children').filter(function (item) { return item.get('child.id') == searchFor; });
var exists = filter.get('length') > 0;
```

However, this makes a remote request to the `child` endpoint with each iteration of the filter, which is unnecessary since it knows the IDs already. Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been dealing with the same problem. The best thing I've come up with is:

```
var searchFor = "someid";
var filtered = parent.get('children').filter(function (item) {
    return item.get('data').child.id == searchFor;
});
var exists = filtered.get('length') > 0;
```

This works (i.e. doesn't make a request), but feels wrong. This works for me with Ember 1.4.0 and Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.3.

Comment: I'll try this out but it looks like what I want since it's accessing metadata instead of hitting whatever code path ends up making a remote request.